# Any better way to post list of object of class on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I want to post my list of object to my controller.

This is my class file:

```
 public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public List<ChildModel> ChildModelObject{ get; set; }
    }

public class ChildModel
    {
        public int ChildId {get; set;}
        public int sum {get; set;}
    }
```

My View Page:

```
 @model Demo.MyModel

      @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
          @{ int i = 0; }
          @foreach (var item in Model.ChildModelObject) //first I am displaying value and then on submit i will post this value
           {
              <input type="hidden" name="@Html.Raw("ChildModelObject[" + i + "].ChildId")" value="@item.ChildId" /> //This is how i am taking value and it is working perfect and i am getting childid.
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sum)
           }
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)//In this i want all childid when form is posted
        {
        }
```

So now when i click on submit button then i want all **childid** in my **MyModel** object.

Can anybody tell me any better approach then what i am doing??

Comment: You have 2 options: use `for` loop so you have iterator in it or use `EditorTemplates`

Comment: @teovankot:Can you post your ans please and i dont want to use any extra variable and if possible use razor hidden controls

Comment: Do not use a `foreach` loop - use `for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChildModelObject.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ChildModelObject[i].ChildId ) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChildModelObject[i].sum) }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Thanks

Comment: But what is the point of this - all your doing is sending extra data acroos to the client and then sending exactly the same back to the server (and in the process opening yourself up to overposting attacks and degrading erformance). Just get the collection again in the POST method if you need it for some reason

Comment: @StephenMuecke:First i am displaying my Model class data and then i am displaying ChildModelObject and then on submit button i am posting this data on controller to save in database.So can you please tell me what wrong i am doing here and suggest me a good way??

Comment: But you not editing/changing any data. Why would you need to save something which has not changed?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Yeah you are right that i am not changing/editing anything but before displaying data on my viewpage i am doing some calculation on my HttpGet method on some fields and that i havent posted here and that i need to save in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Editor Template for your `ChildModel` class like this:

```
@model Demo.ChildModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChildId)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.sum)
```

Place it in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or in your controller EditorTemplates) and name it **ChildModel.cshtml**

And then you can use it like this:

```
@model Demo.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.ChildModelObject)
   <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Note that you don't need any loops MVC generate right bindings itself

Comment: You should make it clear the the template needs to be named `ChildModel.cshtml`